# Servicestack NLog 4.0.43 error

Tags: servicestack, nlog

I am struggling to find the problem, I have removed all `ServiceStack` components and added again.

When I check the references in my project it is correct.

I also tried to load the latest version `Servicestack.NLog 4.0.43`
but when I try to add in my project the error below comes up:
[image]

I am using the versions:

```
Servicestack 4.0.43
Servicestack.Logging.NLog 4.0.42
NLog 3.2.0.0
```

I can build the application, but it shows the error below:

**Could not load file or assembly 'NLog' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

> Server Error in '/jobmanager' Application. Could not load file or
>   assembly 'NLog' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131040) Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'NLog' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'NLog' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog' or one of
>   its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog,
>   Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +210
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +17    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog,
>   Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12496980
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +499    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +131    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +331
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +148
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'NLog,
>   Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +12618692
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12458309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed with the latest version on MyGet. Since you already have v4.0.43 installed you'll need to [clear your NuGet Cache and delete your /packages folder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet#redownloading-myget-packages) to download the latest version.

Comment: Problem fixed! Thanks @mythz